# Counting different values of the same table field in grouped result

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

I have a table that represents a logfile from system events, by date.
I would like, if possible count the occurance of different system events by date.

I can count one value by doing

```
SELECT count(log_id) as login_count, `date` FROM minecraft_log.universal_log 
WHERE plugin=’system’ AND action=’login’ 
GROUP BY DATE( `date` )
ORDER BY DATE( `date` );
```

This will show me how often the plugin "system" generated the event "login". But if I wanted by the same query count another event such as plugin "user" event "delete", how can I do that?

I do not want to add the count for several events but rather have individual counts for 2 different conditions.

Do I need another query?

Comment: You're grouping by slightly different terms from those in your select. this is a no-no and can lead to unexpected results

Comment: Changed to use DATE(), this was a leftover from a different output by year,month,day. Would you group by log_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will get you every combination...

```
  SELECT COUNT(log_id) login_count
       , DATE(date)
       , plugin
       , action
    FROM universal_log l
-- WHERE (x='a' AND y='b') OR (x='m' AND y='n') -- optional parameters
-- you can also write that this way...
-- WHERE (x,y) IN (('a','b'),('m','n'))
   GROUP 
      BY DATE( `date` )
       , plugin
       , action;
```

Comment: This gives you individual counts for different combinations of conditions, as requested !?!?!?!?